# How should I define my constructor (JS)

Tags: javascript

Currently my constructor has been defined like this and working :

```
function Carousel(parent, currentItem, count) {
    var element = parent;
    var count = count;
    var arrPrev = document.createTextNode('‹');
    var arrNext = document.createTextNode('›');
    var cPrevClass = 'cPrevClass';
    var cNextClass = 'cNextClass';
    var crslClass = 'js-Carousel';
    var current = currentItem;

    showArrows();

    /**
    * Create the navigation arrows (prev/next) and attach to carousel.
    */
    function showArrows() {
       // stuff here
       // Event listener (important for my question)
        buttonPrev.addEventListener('click', showPrev);
        buttonNext.addEventListener('click', showNext);
    }
}
```

Because at the time I somehow forgot that I'm supposed to define my class constructor using the `this` keyword (I guess), I now have rewritten it like this :

```
function Carousel(parent, currentItem, count) {
    this.element = parent;
    this.count = count;
    this.current = currentItem;
    this.showArrows = showArrows;
    this.showArrows();
}

/**
 * Create the navigation arrows (prev/next) and attach to carousel.
 */
function showArrows() {
    // stuff here...
    var modal = document.getElementById("netreviews_media_modal");

    // then adding event listener
    buttonPrev.addEventListener('click', showPrev);
    buttonNext.addEventListener('click', showNext);

    modal.appendChild(buttonPrev);
    modal.appendChild(buttonNext);
}

/**
 * Go back
 */
function showPrev() {
    if (Carousel.current == 0) {
        Carousel.current = Carousel.count - 1;
    }
    else {
        Carousel.current = Carousel.current - 1;
    }
    updateModal(element.querySelectorAll('.' + crslClass + ' > ul li > a')[Carousel.current]);
}
```

Now when the `updateModal()` function is running (see at the end of file), I have that error that tells me "Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined"
Of course, `element` isn't defined anymore and just says 'undefined'.

I don't know how to make the `element` point to my class property. Also, `Carousel.current` isn't working either. And I dont know if Im doing good refactoring that. I haven't put all code (//stuff here) but I think its enough...
(FYI I do instantiate my Carousel function later in the code)
Any help appreciated !

Comment: These are not classes they are just functions.

Comment: Indeed. But you aren't helping. How can I access all of these properties from Carousel in later functions?

Comment: Well, you have to instantiate the object if you want to use it

Comment: I did actually, in a later function, but still can't access properties of Carousel in my event listener function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, the best way being the `es6` or `ECMAScript2015` way. Just create a class like so:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar
  }

  baz() {
    console.log(this.bar) // prints Hello world
  }
}

const foo = new Foo('Hello world') // your instance
foo.baz()
```

Another way would be the 'old' way, by creating a function, and you're pretty close. There is however one issue;

```
function Foo(bar) {
  this.bar = bar;

  this.baz = function() {
    console.log(this.bar) // this would point to the anonymous function scope, not the class scope, so this.bar would be undefined
  }
}

const foo = new Foo('Hello world') // your instance
foo.baz() // throws an error
```

As noted in the comments, `this` is not the class or `Foo` scope, but rather the scope of the anonymous function. How i usually fix that, is by using self executing anonymous functions. Now the `this` scope is saved in `self`, you can use it like this;

```
function Foo(bar) {
  this.bar = bar;

  this.baz = (function(self) {
    return function() {
      console.log(self.bar); // prints Hello world
    }
  })(this);
}

const foo = new Foo('Hello world') // your instance
foo.baz() // all good
```

As @Kulvar pointed out, it's also possible (and maybe more performant) to store the `this` in a constant / variable. I personally do not really like this approach, it feels a bit hacky;

```
function Foo(bar) {
  this.bar = bar;

  var self = this;

  this.baz = function() {
    console.log(self.bar) // note the use of `self` instead of `this`
  }
}

const foo = new Foo('Hello world') // your instance
foo.baz() // all good
```

Comment: You should use something like `const anchor = this;` instead of using an IIFE. Performance are better because you don't create a new function with its scope

Comment: Thanks to you both, trying to fully understand it and try it, I ll hit you up when I have :)

Comment: Im trying to make it to work, for now I cant seem to understand why you put baz with quotes... never seen that before ahah I may be msising something. Also I haven't succeed calling my showArrows() function.... I ll update my code to show you what I've tried. Im trying the old way for now

Comment: Ok I got my function showArrows() to run when instantiating Carousel, but I'm still failing at retrieving my 'element' in the showPrev function :(

Comment: Ah `'baz'` is just a string i'm passing. Let me update my answer for clarity.

Comment: Are you trying to get `element` as `this.element` ?

Comment: Oh hey I didn't see your reply, I tried Andrew Bone's answer, I have a fiddle if you want to see... I got to start over again because I'm lost now, with all the answers I've tried... but here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/g55n5za7/1/

Comment: @ErikTerwan Actually I have access to the function but I don't want to execute it outside the class, rather inside ! but on click on my button, it keeps saying 'element' is not defined. It is not a problem if I try (after I instantiate it) carousel.nextPrev(). But that's not what I want... Im really losing it here

Comment: @ErikTerwan Hit me up if you are ok to have a short discussion, I'm so close to it but can't figure out....

Comment: Ive got it to work, finally ! Thanks to your answer that made me realize the issue was with the scope. I put your answer as accepted since it really helped at the end, but all these answers has been really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You're using Carousel in the showPrev function, but Carousel isn't an object, it's a class.

```
function MyClass(arg1)
{
    this.myProperty = arg1;
}

// If you want your class to inherit
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(MyParentClass.prototype);

MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function ()
{
    // You can use this inside a method
    console.log(this.myProperty);
};

MyClass.MyStaticProperty = 42;
MyClass.MyStaticMethod = function ()
{
    // You can't use this here
};

const myObject = new MyClass("Hello, World");
myObject.myMethod();
```

Replace "Carousel" by "this" and attach the method to the class prototype.
Then instanciate your class into an object.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info, I've managed to get it to work thanks to all these answers

Answer (score 1):

To convert this into an actual class it would have to look something like this.

You'll see at the bottom I have a variable that is an instance of the class you can then use call your functions on this variable `carousel.showPrev()` for instance can be called from outside the class.

```
class carouselClass {
  constructor(parent, currentItem, count) {
    this.element = parent;
    this.count = count;
    this.arrPrev = document.createTextNode('‹');
    this.arrNext = document.createTextNode('›');
    this.cPrevClass = 'cPrevClass';
    this.cNextClass = 'cNextClass';
    this.crslClass = 'js-Carousel';
    this.current = currentItem;

    this.showArrows();
  }

  // Create the navigation arrows (prev/next) and attach to carousel.
  showArrows() {
    // stuff here...
    let modal = document.getElementById("netreviews_media_modal");

    // then adding event listener
    buttonPrev.addEventListener('click', this.showPrev);
    buttonNext.addEventListener('click', this.showNext);

    modal.appendChild(buttonPrev);
    modal.appendChild(buttonNext);
  }

  // Go back
  showPrev() {
    if (this.current == 0) {
      this.current = this.count - 1;
    } else {
      this.current--;
    }
    updateModal(this.element.querySelectorAll('.' + this.crslClass + ' > ul li > a')[this.current]);
  }
}

let carousel = new carouselClass('parent', 'currentItem', 'count');
```

Here is some [further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks, about to read that, trying to understand it all ahah, will get back to you asap

Comment: This actually seems to be the easiest way to achieve what I want, I'm gonna try all solutions, haven't been able to succeed yet (cuz Im a noob still ahah)

Comment: So I've tried your solution, as well as the others, but I still can't access my 'element' in the showPrev() function, I don't understand why.....

Comment: And you're using `this.`? Can you use https://jsfiddle.com to make a demo of your app not working, paste the link in here and I'll have a look

Comment: Yes I am, ok Im gonna go fiddle :)

Comment: here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/g55n5za7/ (click on any image to see the carousel, except the last on which is alone and so won't show the carousel)

Comment: When I said `carouselClass('parent', 'currentItem', 'count')` that was just an example, you have to change the 3 values to the correct ones.

Comment: Here is something I wrote a little while ago that uses classes. See if you can apply the same principles to your code https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/xyycj5ta/

Comment: But these are my actual items to be passed as parameters tho... do I need to remove the quotes? I also tried that and I didnt have much luck... I ll look into your example, gtg eat ! thanks

Comment: Have you watched my fiddle ? Im really close but really I can't get why the value of 'element' keeps undefined.... https://jsfiddle.net/g55n5za7/5/

Comment: It looks like it's because of the event listener, maybe move the event listener outside the class.

Comment: Here is a quick example I just threw together that has the controls outside the element (left and right arrow keys)

Comment: Yeah that event listener may be the problem, Im gonna try to put it out... where did you put your example ? thanks!

Comment: Thanks ! I m checking it

Comment: So I included your event listener part out of the class (in my modalOpen function actually), and it works just great ! But I still can't slide by clicking the arrows... wow ! fiddle updated here : https://jsfiddle.net/g55n5za7/19/
:(

Comment: I finally managed to get it to work !! problem was the scope not updating kind of... all good now !!